# Transform table structure

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm

Hello is any sensible algorithm for transforming data table (Table A to Table B) ?

I trying to moving cells , but have no idea how to calculate a place where I should place additional row after my key field Name.

Table A origin

| Name | Salary | Bonus | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John S. | 5000 | Bonus A | 50 |
| John S. |  | Bonus B | 100 |
| Alex G. | 7000 | Bonus C | 150 |
| Alex G. |  | Bonus D | 300 |

Table B (Expected outcome)

| Name | Salary | Bonus | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John S. |  |  | 5000 |
| John S. |  | Bonus A | 50 |
| John S. |  | Bonus B | 100 |
| Alex G. |  |  | 7000 |
| Alex G. |  | Bonus C | 150 |
| Alex G. |  | Bonus D | 300 |

```
Sub TransformTable()

' Setting variables
Dim Name As String
Dim BaseSalary As String
Dim BonusName As String
Dim BonusAmount As Double

'Setting worksheet object
Dim SheetData As Worksheet
Set SheetData = Sheets("SheetData")

'counter for main loop
Dim x As Long

'Setting main object array
Dim MyArray As Variant

Dim Item As Integer
    Item = 1

'reading values from table
    MyArray = Worksheets("SheetData").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Value

'counting last row value

'main loop
    For x = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)

'condition check how many costcenter ids with fixed value
     lstRowSrs = SheetData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Worksheets("SheetData").Cells(Item + 1, 13).Value = MyArray(x, 1)
     Worksheets("SheetData").Cells(Item + 1, 14).Value = MyArray(x, 2)
    
    If MyArray(x, 3) <> "" Then
     
    ' Cells(x, lstRowSrs).EntireRow.Insert
     
     Worksheets("SheetData").Cells(Item + 2, 15).Value = MyArray(x, 3)
     Worksheets("SheetData").Cells(Item + 2, 16).Value = MyArray(x, 4)
     Item = Item + 1

    Else
     Worksheets("SheetData").Cells(Item + 1, 15).Value = MyArray(x, 3)
     Worksheets("SheetData").Cells(Item + 1, 16).Value = MyArray(x, 4)
      
      Item = Item + 1
    End If
    Next x
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you have another excel table ready e.g. `"Table 2"`? Don't you want to get rid of the second table's `Salary` column? Please do clarify.

Comment: One option you could of gone with is to create a copy of table 1, do a few minor modifications (deleting empty rows and moving column data), do a similar thing to original table, stick them together, sort and its done. It would be a few minutes of work and if you had to do the task repeatedly, following that same procedure would be quicker than the per row approach you are using above.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain your desired output using `Power Query`, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365 Excel

- Select some cell in your original table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code.
- Replace the existing code with the **M-Code** below
- Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

The basic algorithm:

- Unpivot the Salary and Amount columns which puts them all into a single column
- the Bonus column will have some duplicates -- remove them if the Attribute column contains "Salary"
- Remove the contents of the Salary column; rename and reorder the columns

***M Code***

```
let

//change table name in next line to actual name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Name", type text}, {"Salary", Int64.Type}, {"Bonus", type text}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}}),

//Unpivot the columns other than Name and Bonus
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Name", "Bonus"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//blank the "bonus" if attribute=salary
    #"Replace Bonus with null" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", 
        each [Bonus],
        each if [Attribute]="Salary" then null else [Bonus],
        Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Bonus"}),

//set columns in correct order
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Replace Bonus with null",{"Name", "Attribute", "Bonus", "Value"}),

//rename "Attribute"=>"Salary" and blank the contents
    Rename = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"Attribute","Salary"},{"Value","Amount"}}),
    blankIt = Table.ReplaceValue(Rename, each [Salary],null, Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Salary"})

in
    blankIt
```

[image]

Comment: thanks man, real it's fast method , especially with large rows numbers. Works pretty fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way. It has the same results as @Sgdva but uses some slightly different techniques. Not better, just something to consider.

```
Sub TransformTable()
    
    Dim vaValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aOutput() As Variant
    Dim lCnt As Long
    
    'put all the values in a 2-d array
    vaValues = Sheet1.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    'make your output array - double the rows of the input
    'it will be too many rows, but you won't run out of room
    ReDim aOutput(1 To UBound(vaValues, 1) * 2, 1 To 4)
    
    'Loop through the 2-d array
    For i = LBound(vaValues, 1) To UBound(vaValues, 1)
        If Len(vaValues(i, 2)) > 0 Then 'a salary exists
            'add a row to the output array
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            aOutput(lCnt, 1) = vaValues(i, 1)
            aOutput(lCnt, 4) = vaValues(i, 2)
        End If
        
        If Len(vaValues(i, 4)) > 0 Then 'a bonus exists
            'add a row to the output array
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            aOutput(lCnt, 1) = vaValues(i, 1)
            aOutput(lCnt, 3) = vaValues(i, 3)
            aOutput(lCnt, 4) = vaValues(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i
    
    'write out the output array in one shot
    Sheet1.Range("G1").Resize(UBound(aOutput, 1), UBound(aOutput, 2)).Value = aOutput
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I changed the logic that you posted as follows

1. Identify the rows to be added
2. Insert them at once (to save memory instead of inserting one by one)
3. Append the data needed by looping again in the rows

For demonstration purposes, I limited the logic to the active sheet and with the data sample shown.
**Demo**
[image]
**Code**

```
Sub Exec_DivideSalary()
Dim CounterRow As Long
Dim RangeRowsToAdd As Range
    For CounterRow = 2 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If Cells(CounterRow, 2).Value <> "" Then ' 1. If Cells(CounterRow, 2).Value <> ""
    If RangeRowsToAdd Is Nothing Then ' 2. If RangeRowsToAdd Is Nothing
    Set RangeRowsToAdd = Rows(CounterRow + 1)
    Else ' 2. If RangeRowsToAdd Is Nothing
    Set RangeRowsToAdd = Union(RangeRowsToAdd, Rows(CounterRow + 1))
    End If ' 2. If RangeRowsToAdd Is Nothing
    End If ' 1. If Cells(CounterRow, 2).Value <> ""
    Next CounterRow
    RangeRowsToAdd.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    For CounterRow = 2 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If Cells(CounterRow, 2).Value <> "" Then ' 3. If Cells(CounterRow, 2).Value <> ""
    Cells(CounterRow + 1, 1).Value = Cells(CounterRow, 1).Value: Cells(CounterRow + 1, 3).Value = Cells(CounterRow, 3).Value: Cells(CounterRow + 1, 4).Value = Cells(CounterRow, 4).Value
    Cells(CounterRow, 4).Value = Cells(CounterRow, 2).Value
    Cells(CounterRow, 2).Value = "": Cells(CounterRow, 3).Value = ""
    End If ' 3. If Cells(CounterRow, 2).Value <> ""
    Next CounterRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello  , thank you for advising . Does RangeRowsToAdd have special method Insert?

Comment: @DimaBilan Nope, regular one, but since it adds up all at once by setting the rows in a range IE: Rows("1:1,5:5,9:9...") it is faster because it only executes once the command insert (insert and delete are time consuming if you do them one by one instead of setting the range and then perform them)